# Замена атрибута у input, type->password и обратно

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно реализовать замену атрибута `type` с `password` на `text` и обратно у `input` по наведению на элемент?

```
<span class="input-group-addon auth" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Само поле:

```
<input type="password" id="input" class="form-control setpass" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Событие при наведении
  $('#basic-addon1').on('mouseover', function(){
    $('#input').attr('type', 'text');
  })
  
  // Событие при потере фокуса
  $('#basic-addon1').on('mouseout', function(){
    $('#input').attr('type', 'password');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="input-group-addon auth" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true">наводим сюда</i></span>
<input type="password" id="input" class="form-control setpass" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
```